# Como faço pra saber quantos vezes, uma mesma inicial, se repete em algumas strings?

Tags: javascript

```js
let strings = ["São Paulo", "Santa Catarina", "São João", "Ja"];

AA = strings.map((n) => {
  count = 0;
  if ("S" === n[0]) {
    count++;
  }
  return count;
});

console.log(AA);
```

O map apenas mostra o resultado da condição passada, mas não é a saída que desejo. Espero um 3, simplesmente, que é o número de string que se inicia com a letra S. Mas como faço isso?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2):

Não está conseguindo obter o resultado esperado porque não está utilizando a ferramenta certa para realizar a tarefa.
O método `Array.prototype.map()` tem a finalidade de transformar cada elemento dum [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) segundo uma função callback, passada por argumento, e retornar um novo `Array` de mesmo tamanho que o `Array` cujo seus elemento sejam o resultado dessa transformação.

`Array.prototype.map()` não é o melhor método para se fazer um contador, então o apresento algumas alternativas.

1. Use a instrução [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) para cria um laço de iteração numa variável local ao laço `i` variando de `0` até o número de cidades menos 1.
   Para cada `cidades[i]` verifica se a primeira letra é `"S"` condicionando o incremento de um contador `count`. Nota que para verificar se uma [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) começa com determinados caracteres pode ser utilizado o método [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).

```js
let cidades = ["São Paulo", "Santa Catarina", "São João", "Jaú"];
let count = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < cidades.length; i++) {
  if (cidades[i][0] == "S") count++;  //if (cidades[i].startsWith("S")) count++;
}

console.log(`São ${count} cidades iniciadas com a letra S.`);
```

2. A instrução [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) percorre objetos iterativos, o `cidades` , permitindo incrementar um um contador `count` caso a cidade `c` inicie com a letra `"S"`.

```js
let cidades = ["São Paulo", "Santa Catarina", "São João", "Jaú"];
let count = 0;

for (const c of cidades){
  if (c[0] == "S") count++; //if (c.startsWith("S")) count++;  
}

console.log(`São ${count} cidades iniciadas com a letra S.`);
```

3. O método [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) cria um novo `Array` com todos os elementos que passaram na função teste que verifica se cidade `c` inicia com a letra `"S"`.

```js
let cidades = ["São Paulo", "Santa Catarina", "São João", "Jaú"];
let count = cidades.filter((c)=> c[0] == "S").length;
//let count = cidades.filter((c)=> c.startsWith("S")).length;

console.log(`São ${count} cidades iniciadas com a letra S.`);
```

4. O método [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) executa uma função redutora para cada elemento `cidades`, incrementado o acumulador da função redutora caso a cidade `c` inicie com `"S"`.

```js
let cidades = ["São Paulo", "Santa Catarina", "São João", "Jaú"];
let count = cidades.reduce((t, c) => (c[0] == "S") ? ++t : t, 0);
//let count = cidades.reduce((t, c)=> c.startsWith("S") ? ++t : t, 0);

console.log(`São ${count} cidades iniciadas com a letra S.`);
```